# Gmail query after: or newer:than: doesn't properly accept unix-like timestamps

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using `q` parameter inside Gmail API request. It is documented that it accepts same queries as Gmail web app.

I used this query: `newer_than:1480338055000`

However, it is not showing any messages (tested it on both API calls and Gmail client)

However `older_than:` accepts unix-like timestamp.

I am currently in GMT+1 timezone if that would matter.

Why doesn't it work properly and what are other alternatives to query messages that appeared after specific time (should be precise at least by 1 hour)

Comment: Hi Kunok, I previously was trying to use this method as well, however if you read the docs for the advanced q param there is no mention of supporting UNIX time stamps. They instead use relative times to now using dmy format. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en Generally querying as you are looking for would be done using the history API rather than the thread/message search.

Comment: @GrantWatters could you please share example of your query?

Comment: I took a look at my code rather than going off memory. It looks like I use 'before' and 'after' with a timestamp rather than 'newer_than' and 'older_than'. The 'newer/older' verbs use the form: 'newer_than:2d'. And the 'before/after' verbs use the form: 'before:[timestamp]'. Hope thats helpful!

Comment: @GrantWatters I already have a case where I use timpestamps  by combining `before:` and `after:` with values such as `2016/01/01`, but this is not precise enough. I need somehow to query messages by difference in hours or minutes, if possible.

Comment: @Kunok You can use seconds since epoch to be more precise if you would like. E.g `after:2016/01/01 <=> after:1451606400`

Comment: Oh I see so it's seconds, not miliseconds since Jan 1 1970?

Comment: @Kunok That's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `before` or `after` with second accuracy. Just give seconds since the epoch:

```
after:2016/01/01 <=> after:1451606400
```